Push-connectors are destroyed in electrolizer?
Can KOH crack up plastic bags n push-connectors? While draining my electrolyzer, some of the KOH got on the push connectors. I didn’t notice it and it dried and a few hours later, it is destroyed. Does this happen for every plastic with KOH? Does NaOH do the same? I’m starting to hate KOH. The use connectors I used are from Amazon. I sadly don’t remember the brand but they are plastic. 



Look up the plastic used in your connectors. These fittings are likely made of cheaper untreated PBT, which develops cracks upon prolonged contact with an alkali. There are Duranex or Ultradur-branded PBTs with increased resistance against basic media.

BTW, I detest working with NaOH -- it slowly destroys glassware, and is quite caustic to skin and immediately damages eyes, and seems to wet its way through supposedly tight connections almost as if it were superfluid He (OK, a slight exaggeration ;-) Perhaps consider a different project.
